# continuity of pointwise limit of continuous functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges pointwise to $f$ i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) =f(x)$.

Define $P_{m,n}=\{x||f_m(x)-f(x)\leq 1/n\}$, $Q_n=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} (P_{m,n})^{\circ}$, $R=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}Q_n$.

{$(A)^{\circ}$ is interior of A}

Questions:

(1) Show that $R$ consists of all $t$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous.

(2) Define $F_{m,n}=\{x||\forall k\geq0~f_m(x)-f_{m+k}(x)\leq 1/n\}.$ Show that $F_{m,n}$ is closed, $F_{m,n}\subset P_{m,n}$, and $[0,1]=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}F_{m,n}$

(3) Prove: $[0,~1]~\ni~x$ exists such that $f$ is continuous in $x$.

I solved (1) by definition, and (3) with Baire category theorem.
But I have a difficulty in (2). $F_{m,n}\subset P_{m,n}$ is easy, but the others are difficult. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

$F_{m,n}=\cap_k \{x:f_m(x)-f_{m+k}(x) \leq \frac 1  n\}$. Intersection of closed sets is closed. $\{x:f_m(x)-f_{m+k}(x) \leq \frac 1  n\}$ is closed becasue it is the inverse image of $(-\infty, \frac 1  n]$ under a continuous function.

The fact that $[0,1]$ is the union of $F_{m,n}$ over $m$ is simple  restatement of the fact that $(f_n(x))$ is a Cauchy sequence for each $x$.

Comment: Sorry, what is "it is the iverts eim gag of..."  ?

Comment: @eosa I think it should mean "it is the inverse image of"

Comment: I understand. But, (-∞,1/n] is not closed, so the definition of continuous function cannot be used ?

Comment: @eosa $(-\infty, \frac 1 n]$  is a closed set in the real line.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood.